# How to install an appimage file in linux fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, appimage

I am new to Linux and I'm using the Fedora distro.

I encountered a problem while trying to install an app. The app is in AppImage format, but when I try to run it, I receive an error message saying, "Could not display AppImage."

I have tried searching for a solution to this error, but unfortunately, I haven't found any relevant results.

Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Exactly how did you _"try to run it"_?  What are the file permissions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you would need to make the file executable.
(chmod +x filename.appImage)
Then run ./filename.appImage to run the app itself.
However, if you want to integrate it follow the steps described here
https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).